# Moderation strike: a tired lunatic (4)

Tags: cryptic-clues

Which four-letter word fits the clue "Moderation strike: a tired lunatic"?

Disclaimer:

> 1. I'm a Dutch native speaker, we have a cryptic crossword tradition as well, but I've never seriously tried an English one. I know they are different, please don't judge me on that.
>  2. Obviously, I'm trying to replicate the effect of [this Academia.SE question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/196930/33097) - which was no doubt inspired by [the actions documented here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389843/295232). I'm aware that it's possible to delist a question from the Hot Network Questions list; still, this seems appropriate for a protest like this.

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147792/discussion-on-question-by-glorfindel-moderation-strike-a-tired-lunatic-4) as they pertained to the strike and not the puzzle posting. (Conversation about the strike is better done elsewhere.)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I believe the word you're looking for is

> **MOON**

Wordplay:

> strike the letters **ATIRED** from the word MO**DERATI**ON, getting something "lunatic" in the literal sense.

Who knows? Maybe this'll be one small step towards progress.

Comment: rot13('Yhangvp' vf obgu na nantenz pyhr (abg fher vs gung'f arprffnel va guvf pnfr) naq ersref gb gur fbyhgvba. Vg erznva hafher jurgure gur frpbaq unys bs gur pyhr nccyvrf gb gur chmmyr nhgube ...)

Comment: @Glorfindel that makes sense, although (at least in english cryptics) rot13(gur qrsvavgvba naq jbeqcynl ner nyzbfg nyjnlf pbzcyrgryl frcnengr - hayrff bs pbhefr vg'f na &yvg pyhr, jurer gur jubyr pyhr vf obgu jbeqcynl naq qrsvavgvba, juvpu vfa'g gur pnfr urer. gb or fgevpgyl pbeerpg lbh cebonoyl fubhyq unir unq na nantenz vaqvpngbe *naq* n frcnengr qrsvavgvba, ohg V qvqa'g pbzcynva va zl nafjre orpnhfr boivbhfyl gur fhesnpr ernqvat jnf zber vzcbegnag). still, a solid clue, especially for a first attempt!